# «Раздался крик: "Срочно (?) свет!"» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Нужен ли тут какой-либо знак препинания?

**Раздался крик: "Срочно (?) свет!"**

(В значении "включите" или "дайте".)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Извините, Артём, но я не согласна с Вашей правкой. По правилам скобки от основного текста отделяются пробелом. Впритык к тексту на сайте обычно ставят скобки тогда, когда в вопросе речь идет **конкретно о запятой**. (_Нужна ли запятая в указанном месте?_ — она ведь от слова пробелом не отделяется.) Здесь вопрос — о знаке **вообще** (нужен или не нужен?).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: простите, Римма, и спасибо, что сказали. Это верно, но из знаков отделяется только тире от предыдущего слова, поэтому большая вероятность, что правильным окажется не тире, а как раз один из большого количества неотделяемых знаков. Но если всё равно не согласны, поправьте обратно.

Comment: Эх-эх! — а я так старалась... Не стоит рассыпать искры. Пусть будет.

Comment: Какие искры?.. Может, Вы и правы. Вы считаете, что если есть вариант хоть одного знака (тире), "под него" надо отделять пробелом и в общем случае? Я же тоже хочу разобраться. Не хочу навязывать свой вариант. А то буду похож на тирана, деспота и пр. :(

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: просто скажите, моя логика, что остальные знаки, кроме тире, не отделяются и скорее могут оказаться правильными, Вам не кажется убедительной? Скажете "нет" — я сам верну пробелы. Не хочу, чтобы Вам мой вариант резал глаз.

Comment: Так диалога и не получилось. :/

Comment: Да получилось, Артем, получилось. Просто я руководствовалась своим видением (тире), а Вы — всеми остальными знаками. Хорошо, а если вообще не надо никакого знака между словами — как быть? Поэтому я Вам так и ответила: "Пусть будет" (имея в виду **Ваш** вариант). P. S. А бдительный модератор со своими предупреждениями — уже близко-близко.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: рад, что Вы прокомментировали (только сейчас увидел *:)*). Вы меня убедили: действительно, если тире можно предложить, пусть и ошибочно (без всяких намёков на его неуместность в данном случае), надо отделять с двух сторон пробелами, а не отделять перед и отделять после только в вопросах именно о запятой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Раздался крик: "Срочно — свет!"** (*Срочно [дайте] свет!* — наречие в начале предложения.)
При пропуске (отсутствии) сказуемого и наличии паузы ставится тире.
Вы сами пишете: *в значении "включите" или "дайте"* — эти глаголы не произносятся, но подразумеваются кричащим.

[Все случаи постановки тире](http://rus.1sep.ru/article.php?ID=200202402)

**Раздался крик: "Срочно! Свет!"**
В экстренных ситуациях, требующих быстрого принятия решения, и в случаях, когда окружающие тебя понимают однозначно, лишних слов решительный человек обычно не говорит. А значимые он произносит четко, отрывисто.

Пунктуационный выбор — в зависимости от контекста — за вами. Без знаков никак не обойтись.

> — Джек! Очнись! Джек! Ты меня слышишь?! Скорую! Срочно!

Возможен, как мне кажется, ещё один вариант.
**Раздался крик: "Свет, срочно!"** (*[Дайте] Cвет, срочно!* — наречие в конце предложения.)

> — Срочно домой! За колбой, мигом!

Answer (score 2):

**Раздался крик: "Свет! Срочно!"**

Крикнуть всю фразу сложно, поэтому ее надо разделить на два восклицательных предложения.  Сначала называют нужный предмет, а потом говорят о срочности.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Раздался крик: “Срочно(?) свет!”***
>
> Нужен ли тут какой-либо знак препинания?

Нужен. Но только при наличии паузы *в крике* после слова "срочно".

В отсутствие паузы никаких знаков препинания после "срочно" не требуется:

***Срочно свет!***